# EvaluateJavascript Using Android WebView with API level 18

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I've been developing an Android app for my business for a long time and it's been working fine, using a webview and calling back and forth between native features. In case it's relevant, here's the Java entry point to my app:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    final Context that = this;
    myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this, this), "Android");

    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            myWebView.evaluateJavascript("pageFinished()", null);
        }
    });

    pm = this.getPackageManager();

    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);

    Window window = getWindow();
    //window.setStatusBarColor(Color.parseColor("#3596d4"));

    myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    filter.addAction(getResources().getString(R.string.activity_intent_filter_action));
    registerReceiver(myBroadcastReceiver, filter);

    mDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(that, this);
    myWebView.setOnTouchListener(touchListener);
}
```

Now when I set the minimum version to 18 in my gradle file, some lines got marked by Android Studio as 'not supported by API 18', most notably my `myWebView.evaluateJavascript` calls, but also some other stuff like `WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled`.

How can I do `evaluateJavascript` in API 18?

Also in some places, when I call `evaluateJavascript`, I expect a response back, for example:

```
    myWebView.evaluateJavascript("Back.go()", new ValueCallback<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onReceiveValue(String canGoBack) {
            if (canGoBack.equals("false")) {
                moveTaskToBack(true);
            } else {
                // don't need to do anything, already called Back.go()
                // that means the javascript already handled navigation
            }
        }
    });
```

Will that be possible with API 18?

Comment: Note, the Google Play Store is not allowing uploaded apps to have less than SDK level 24.  So, if this app needs to be distributed via the App Stores, you have to set the minimum SDK level to 24 or above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I do evaluateJavascript in API 18?

Use `loadUrl("javascript:..."), where the`...` is your JavaScript code.

> Will that be possible with API 18?

No, sorry. The closest thing is to have your JavaScript code call something on your `WebAppInterface` that you injected via `addJavascriptInterface()`.

Note that at the present time [only ~4% of Android devices using the Play Store are running API Level 18 or older](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/).